# googleapi: Error 403: Permission 'cloudfunctions.functions.create' denied on resource

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to create a GCP function using terraform. using gcloud SDK default login for authentication.

Code for creating a function:

```
resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "test"{
  name = "python-app-function"
  project = var.projNumber
  region = "europe-central2"
  runtime = "python39"
  trigger_http = true
  source_archive_bucket = google_storage_bucket.bucket_for_python_application.name
  source_archive_object = google_storage_bucket.bucket_for_python_application.name
}
```

I know that `source_archive_bucket = google_storage_bucket.bucket_for_python_application.name` && `source_archive_object = google_storage_bucket.bucket_for_python_application.name` is not right.

But google api won't let me even to start crating a function:
[image]

Because I'm using a SDK auto login for authentication I gave myself every possible role:

[image]

But `Owner` role already has this permission:

[image]

I'm stuck.

Comment: Are you sure that you are authenticated with the right user when running `terraform` ? Have you done `gcloud auth application-default login` (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/provider_reference#running-terraform-on-your-workstation) ?

Comment: Yep, I've used exactly `gcloud auth application-default login` to login through SDK.

Comment: Are you able to create other resources, such as buckets ? Owner role is enough to create buckets.

Comment: Yeah I have a resource for creating a bucket and a zip archive in it, it works fine. my `main.tf` fails on creating a function, but even it will fail it still creates intended bucket.

Comment: Ok I think I've understood : if `var.projectNumber` is the project number, then `project = var.projNumber` is wrong. It should be the project name, not the number.

Comment: Changed `project = "My First Project` and still getting 403 error.

Comment: Sorry, I meant Project Id, not name. What is weird is that you don't have issues with other resources. Have you specified `project` in other resources ? Or maybe you have already set it in your `provider` block ?

Comment: That actually worked. Thank You so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `project` field in your resource definition should be set to the **project id**, not the project number (assuming `var.projNumber` is your project number).

By the way, if you are working with a single project, you can put the project directly on your provider block, thus avoiding to repeat the project id in all of your resources :

```
provider "google" {
  project = "my-project-id"
  region  = "us-central1"
}
```